# Time series convert/summarise series of values into a single value

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistics

Hi I have a time series dataset which looks like this

```
Date             Value1
2021/08/01        2
```

and

```
Date             Value1
2020/08/01        4
```

and

```
Date             Value1
2019/08/01        6
```

I want to compare the 2021 data with 2020 first and compare 2021 data with 2019. I am doing a percent change calculation to get both the values, which will be 2021 vs 2020 and 2021 vs 2019. I want to now interpret these two changes into a single value i.e.

For example, if change in Value1 from 2021 vs 2020 is 10%, change in Value1 from 2021 vs 2019 is 15%, I want to summarize this to a single value. What would be the better version to summarise other than just doing a plain average of these two ((10+15)/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with including a second order term to capture acceleration/deceleration of the trend.